# Question about geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, geodesic, metric-geometry

On the [Wikipedia page for Geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Metric_geometry), it's stated that a curve $\gamma : I → M$ from an interval $I$ of the reals to the metric space $M$ is a geodesic if there is a constant $v \geq 0$ such that for any $t \in I$ there is a neighborhood $J$ of $t$ in $I$ such that for any $t_1, t_2 \in J$ we have $d(\gamma (t_1),\gamma (t_2)) = v\left|t_1-t_2\right|.$

I am wondering how any such curve $\gamma$ is locally a minimal distance function, i.e. if $x,y \in M$ is connected by a curve $\tilde{\gamma}(t) : [a,b] \to M$ and $\gamma(t) : [a,b] \to M$ is a geodesic connecting the two points, then the length of $\tilde{\gamma}$ is greater than or equal to the length of $\gamma$ with equality possible only in the case where $\tilde{\gamma}$ is a geodesic according to the definition just given.

In general, what is the intuition behind the definition of a geodesic via the statement $d(\gamma (t_1),\gamma (t_2)) = v\left|t_1-t_2\right|$?

I realize that there are geodesics which are not the distance minimizing curves, e.g. two portions of great circles in the Riemann sphere. If a surface does not have any holes (i.e. genus is zero) and is complete, does that guarantee that geodesics minimize distance globally?

Comment: Genus is irrelevant. The “right” geodesic minimizes globally, but certainly not necessarily all. With completeness, there is always a distance-minimizing geodesic.

Comment: Quick comment: I usually call such a curve a constant speed geodesic.

Comment: Are you sure that the 2nd paragraph is what you intended to write? As it stands, there is nothing "local" there. Did you mean to write  that there exists a geodesic $\gamma$ connecting $x, y$, or that for every $\gamma$ connecting $x, y$, or something else...? Also, the expression "locally a minimal distance function" does not really make sense.

Comment: I think this definition is related to the triangular inequality: in the situation of the first paragraph, take $t_1,t_2,t_3\in J$ with $t_1<t_2<t_3$ and investigate what happens. Doing so it should be possible to understand that if one tries to deform $\gamma$ locally, its length can only get higher than that.

Comment: Thanks @DryBones, could you elaborate as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer resides in the fact, which motivates the aforementioned definition of *geodesic* in a metric space, that for any $t_1,t_2,t_3\in J$ with $t_l<t_2<t_3$, in the situation of the first paragraph, we have

$$d(\gamma(t_1),\gamma(t_3))=v(t_3-t_1)=v(t_2-t_1)+v(t_3-t_2)=d(\gamma(t_1),\gamma(t_2))+d(\gamma(t_2),\gamma(t_3)).$$

Put into words, this means that, locally, equality holds for the triangle inequality involving points of a geodesic $\gamma$.

Let's fulfill the details. We would like to check that a geodesic $\gamma$ is locally minimizing. First, recall that the *length* of a curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to M$ in a metric space $M$ is defined as the supremum

$$\ell(\gamma):=\sup_P\sum_{\substack{t,s\in P\\t<s}}d(\gamma(t),\gamma(s)),$$

where $P$ runs over all partitions of $[a,b]$, i.e. all finite subsets $P\subset [a,b]$ such that $a,b\in P$.

A curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to M$ is *locally minimizing* if, for all $t\in [a,b]$, there's a neighbourhood $J\subset [a,b]$ of $t$ such that every curve $\tilde\gamma:[a',b']\to M$ with $[a',b']\subset J$, $\tilde\gamma(a')=\gamma(a')$, $\tilde\gamma(b')=\gamma(b')$ satisfies the inequality

$$\ell(\gamma')\le\ell(\tilde\gamma),$$

where $\gamma':[a',b']\to M$ denotes the restriction of $\gamma$ to $[a',b']$.

Now, let $\gamma:[a,b]\to M$ be a geodesic, pick some $t\in[a,b]$ and let $J\subset[a,b]$ be a neighbourhood of $t$ such that for any $t_1,t_2\in J$, $t_1<t_2$, we have

$$d(\gamma(t_1),\gamma(t_2))=v(t_2-t_1)$$

for some constant $v\ge0$.

Take $[a',b']\subset J$ and consider the restriction $\gamma':[a',b']\to M$ of $\gamma$ to $[a',b']$. Then $\ell(\gamma')=d(\gamma'(a'),\gamma'(b'))$. Indeed, for any partition $P\subset[a',b']$ we have

$$\sum_{\substack{t,s\in P\\t<s}}d(\gamma'(t),\gamma'(s))=\sum_{\substack{t,s\in P\\t<s}}v(s-t)=v(b'-a')=d(\gamma'(a'),\gamma'(b')).$$

Thus,

$$\ell(\gamma')=\sup_P\sum_{\substack{t,s\in P\\t<s}}d(\gamma'(t),\gamma'(s))=d(\gamma'(a'),\gamma'(b')).$$

Finally, take a curve $\tilde\gamma:[a',b']\to M$ such that $\tilde\gamma(a')=\gamma'(a')$, $\tilde\gamma(b')=\gamma'(b')$. Then $\ell(\gamma')\le\ell(\tilde\gamma)$. Indeed, by the triangle inequality, for any partition $P\subset[a',b']$, we have

$$d(\tilde\gamma(a'),\tilde\gamma(b'))\le\sum_{\substack{t,s\in P\\t<s}}d(\tilde\gamma(t),\tilde\gamma(s)).$$

But

$$\ell(\gamma')=d(\gamma'(a'),\gamma'(b'))=d(\tilde\gamma(a'),\tilde\gamma(b'))$$

and

$$\sum_{\substack{t,s\in P\\t<s}}d(\tilde\gamma(t),\tilde\gamma(s))\le\sup_P\sum_{\substack{t,s\in P\\t<s}}d(\tilde\gamma(t),\tilde\gamma(s))=\ell(\tilde\gamma).$$

Comment: Did you check everything?